# Update table using CURSOR and procedure result

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

I have stored procedure which returns a value and I want to loop all rows in table to update column. I'm using MSSQL.
I was planning to use CURSOR but I wasn’t able to get it work:

```
SELECT SeqNrColumn FROM MAP_DATA -- All SeqNrColumn values in table are NULL

-- DECLARE VARIABLES
DECLARE @SeqNrColumn int
DECLARE @NewSeqNrColumn int

DECLARE DataCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
        SeqNrColumn
    FROM MAP_DATA

OPEN DataCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM DataCursor
INTO @SeqNrColumn

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC @NewSeqNrColumn = [dbo].[ipSU_NXT_MAP_SEQNR] -- I need to run this procedure against all rows to get unique SeqNr
    UPDATE MAP_DATA SET SeqNrColumn = @NewSeqNrColumn;

END 

CLOSE DataCursor
DEALLOCATE DataCursor
```

Any help? (This is my first time creating a CURSOR loop).

I tried update table using stored procedure result and I cannot modify that stored procedure.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hey, I'm using MSSQL server

Comment: This looks like you are trying to create your own version of an identity or sequence. I would suggest you take this approach. The main reason your code here is failing is because your update statement has no where clause, so it is updating every row in MAP_DATA each iteration of your cursor. But you also forgot to iterate inside your cursor so it will just get stuck in an endless loop. This almost certainly could be rewritten as a set based approach instead of row by row.

Answer (score 0):

`All SeqNrColumn values in table are NULL` means you set `@SeqNrColumn` to null, and then you don't do anything with it. `UPDATE MAP_DATA SET SeqNrColumn = @NewSeqNrColumn;` without any `WHERE` clause will set all the rows in `MAP_DATA` to the same value. What you really need is some way to uniquely identify a `MAP_DATA` row (a Natural Key). You can use the cursor to fetch the natural key, then generate the `@NewSeqNrColumn`, and update `MAP_DATA` with a where clause that uses the natural key.

I assume you have a reason for the `MAP_DATA.SeqNrColumn` not being an *identity* column. If it's `NULL`, it's not the primary key. You will need either the natural key or the primary key of that table for your cursor to behave as you expect it to.